# How can I improve the speed of pandas rows operations?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, data-science

I have a large .csv file that has 11'000'000 rows and 3 columns: id ,magh , mixid2.
What I have to do is to select the rows with the same id and then check if these rows have the same mixid2; if True I remove the rows, If False I initialize a class with the information of the selected rows.
That is my code:

```
obs=obs.set_index('id')
obs=obs.sort_index()
#dropping elements with only one mixid2 and filling S
ID=obs.index.unique()
S=[]
good_bye_list = []
for i in tqdm(ID):
    app=obs.loc[i]
    if len(np.unique([app['mixid2'],])) != 1:
        #fill the class list
        S.append(star(app['magh'].values,app['mixid2'].values,z_in))
    else :
    #drop
        good_bye_list.append(i)

obs=obs.drop(good_bye_list)
```

The .csv file is very large so it takes 40 min to compute everything.
How can I improve the speed??

Thank you for the help.

This is the .csv file:

```
id,mixid2,magh
3447001203296326,557,14.25
3447001203296326,573,14.25
3447001203296326,525,14.25
3447001203296326,541,14.25
3447001203296330,540,15.33199977874756
3447001203296330,573,15.33199977874756
3447001203296333,172,17.476999282836914
3447001203296333,140,17.476999282836914
3447001203296333,188,17.476999282836914
3447001203296333,156,17.476999282836914
3447001203296334,566,15.626999855041506
3447001203296334,534,15.626999855041506
3447001203296334,550,15.626999855041506
3447001203296338,623,14.800999641418455
3447001203296338,639,14.800999641418455
3447001203296338,607,14.800999641418455
3447001203296344,521,12.8149995803833
3447001203296344,537,12.8149995803833
3447001203296344,553,12.8149995803833
3447001203296345,620,12.809000015258787
3447001203296345,543,12.809000015258787
3447001203296345,636,12.809000015258787
3447001203296347,558,12.315999984741213
3447001203296347,542,12.315999984741213
3447001203296347,526,12.315999984741213
3447001203296352,615,12.11299991607666
3447001203296352,631,12.11299991607666
3447001203296352,599,12.11299991607666
3447001203296360,540,16.926000595092773
3447001203296360,556,16.926000595092773
3447001203296360,572,16.926000595092773
3447001203296360,524,16.926000595092773
3447001203296367,490,15.80799961090088
3447001203296367,474,15.80799961090088
3447001203296367,458,15.80799961090088
3447001203296369,639,15.175000190734865
3447001203296369,591,15.175000190734865
3447001203296369,623,15.175000190734865
3447001203296369,607,15.175000190734865
3447001203296371,460,14.975000381469727
3447001203296373,582,14.532999992370605
3447001203296373,614,14.532999992370605
3447001203296373,598,14.532999992370605
3447001203296374,184,14.659000396728516
3447001203296374,203,14.659000396728516
3447001203296374,152,14.659000396728516
3447001203296374,136,14.659000396728516
3447001203296374,168,14.659000396728516
3447001203296375,592,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,608,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,624,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,92,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,76,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,108,14.723999977111815
3447001203296375,576,14.723999977111815
3447001203296376,132,14.0649995803833
3447001203296376,164,14.0649995803833
3447001203296376,180,14.0649995803833
3447001203296376,148,14.0649995803833
3447001203296377,168,13.810999870300293
3447001203296377,152,13.810999870300293
3447001203296377,136,13.810999870300293
3447001203296377,184,13.810999870300293
3447001203296378,171,13.161999702453613
3447001203296378,187,13.161999702453613
3447001203296378,155,13.161999702453613
3447001203296378,139,13.161999702453613
3447001203296380,565,13.017999649047852
3447001203296380,517,13.017999649047852
3447001203296380,549,13.017999649047852
3447001203296380,533,13.017999649047852
3447001203296383,621,13.079999923706055
3447001203296383,589,13.079999923706055
3447001203296383,605,13.079999923706055
3447001203296384,541,12.732000350952148
3447001203296384,557,12.732000350952148
3447001203296384,525,12.732000350952148
3447001203296385,462,12.784000396728516
3447001203296386,626,12.663999557495115
3447001203296386,610,12.663999557495115
3447001203296386,577,12.663999557495115
3447001203296389,207,12.416000366210938
3447001203296389,255,12.416000366210938
3447001203296389,223,12.416000366210938
3447001203296389,239,12.416000366210938
3447001203296390,607,12.20199966430664
3447001203296390,591,12.20199966430664
3447001203296397,582,16.635000228881836
3447001203296397,598,16.635000228881836
3447001203296397,614,16.635000228881836
3447001203296399,630,17.229999542236328
3447001203296404,598,15.970000267028807
3447001203296404,631,15.970000267028807
3447001203296404,582,15.970000267028807
3447001203296408,540,16.08799934387207
3447001203296408,556,16.08799934387207
3447001203296408,524,16.08799934387207
3447001203296408,572,16.08799934387207
3447001203296409,632,15.84000015258789
3447001203296409,616,15.84000015258789
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Comment: You could use a group by or a pivot with count. In brief a Pandas function that does aggregation with count in one shot.

Comment: Sorry guys. I added a piece of the .csv

Comment: And what are `obs` and `tqdm` and `star`?

Comment: obs is the dataframe. Tqdm is this https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm. Star is a class.

Comment: Use `awk` (or C directly), it will be at least one order of magnitude faster than Python.

Comment: With awk I can't fill my classes

Comment: @MicheleAvella You can prefilter with `awk`, and then use the result with pandas, if performance is critical.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to use awk. Thanks.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa can you suggest me a link of a tutorial to learn how to do this with awk?

Comment: Does your code do what you expect? Have you *tested* it? I don't see how `check if these rows have the same mixid2` and `if len(np.unique([app['mixid2'],])) != 1:` are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.

In pandas the rule of thumb is that raw loops are always slower than the dedicated functions. To apply a function to a sub-DataFrame of rows that fulfill certain criteria you can use `groupby`

In your case the function is a bit ... unpythonic as the instantiation of `S` is a side effect and the deleting of rows you are currenty iterating over is dangerous. For example in a dictionary you should never do this. That said, you can create a function like this:

```
In [37]: def my_func(df): 
    ...:     if df['mixid2'].nunique() == 1: 
    ...:         return None 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         S.append(df['mixid2']) 
    ...:         return df
```

and apply it to you DataFrame via

```
S = []
obs.groupby('id').apply(my_func)
```

This iterates over all subdataframes with the same `id` and drops them if there is exactly one unique value in `mixid2`. Otherwise it appends the values to a list `S`

The resulting DataFrame is 3 rows shorter

```
Out[38]: 
                                   id  mixid2       magh
id                                                      
3447001203296326 0   3447001203296326     557  14.250000
                 1   3447001203296326     573  14.250000
...                               ...     ...        ...
3447001203296409 98  3447001203296409     632  15.840000
                 99  3447001203296409     616  15.840000

[97 rows x 3 columns]
```

and `S` contains 28 elements. That you could pass into the `star` constructor just as you did.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I tried with a reduced file but your way is slower than mine.

Your takes 33 sec to remove the rows
Mine takes 19 sec to do everything

Comment: Sorry!! Your way is faster, I was wrong. Tank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to `groupby` and exclude all the elements where `mixid2` appears more than 1 times using `set_index`. To get the original shape, we use `reset_index` after the filtering.

```
df = obs.set_index('mixid2').loc[~df.groupby('mixid2').count().id.eq(1)].reset_index()
df.shape
(44, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, if I understood you correctly. But what you can do is first remove duplicates in your dataframe and then use the groupby function to get all the remaining data points with same id:

```
# dropping all duplicates based on id an mixid2
df.drop_duplicates(["id", "mixid2"], inplace=True)

# then iterate over all groups:
for index, grp in df.groupby(["id"]):
    pass  # do stuff here with the grp
```

Normally it is a good idea to rely on pandas internal functions, since they are mostly optimised quite well.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = app.groupby(['id','mixid2'], as_index=False).agg('count')
new_df = new_df[new_df['magh'] > 1]
```

then pass new_df to your function.